# How to generate a specific directory path?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm working on directory path issue, where I want to generate a specific dir path that I want to like `mkdir -p root/PnG/bd_proc01/dataprep/JY2018/JD331/uuid -t/` where i want the UUID place to get filled with generated "UUID -t" which is time based UUID in shell. and once that path is created, the path should be stored in a variable.

and I also want a script that looks for a specific full path based on UUID given as input.

Can anyone can help me with this please ?

Thx,
kumar

Comment: like: `path = '//some//long//path//%s -t' % generated_uuid` ?

Comment: Put `uuid -t` in backticks `\`` in your shell script: `mkdir -p root/PnG/bd_proc01/dataprep/JY2018/JD331/\`uuid -t\`/`

Answer (score 2):

**`bash`:**

Using `uuidgen` (comes with `uuid-runtime`) in GNU/Linux:

```
dir_path="root/PnG/bd_proc01/dataprep/JY2018/JD331/"$(uuidgen -t)"/"
mkdir -p "$dir_path" || unset dir_path
```

Saving the required path in variable `dir_path` (getting the time based UUID using command substitution - `$(uuidgen -t)`), creating the directory; if the directory creation failed, `unset`-ing the variable. As you can imagine, for successful directory creation case, you would get the directory name in the variable `dir_path`.

---

**`python`:**

Using `uuid`, similar logic to the `bash` one:

```
import os 
import uuid
# `uuid.uuid1()` creates time (and host) based UUID
dir_path = os.path.join('root/PnG/bd_proc01/dataprep/JY2018/JD331/', \
                          '{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
try:
    # Recursive directory creation (like `mkdir -p`)
    os.makedirs(dir_path)
# You can be precise here rather than catching the whole Exception class
except Exception: 
    del dir_path
```

Comment: can you also suggest how to get JY2018 and JD331 automatically

Comment: @Arun How are you planning to get those values? There is no info whatsoever in your question about that.

Comment: I'm want those values to get automatically when i execute the script and that value should be like JY(JobYear)+CurrentYear and JD(JobDay)+dayofYear in that dir path so that I don't have to give those values everytime in path. And sorry for the vague question.

Comment: I tried this but I'm not happy with it.`today = date.today()
currentday=('JD'+str(today.day))
currentyear=('JY'+str(today.year))

# uuid.uuid1() creates time (and host) based UUID
dir_path = os.path.join('root/PnG/bd_proc01/dataprep/JY+'(today.year)/'JD'+(today.day)/ \
                          '{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))`

Comment: @Arun That's different. Please ask a new question.